# GNU Make default to low resolution time?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

GNU Make by default uses high resolution time stamps on files. Is there any way to turn that off for the whole makefile? (Not just in [.LOW_RESOLUTION_TIME special targets](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html).)

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot use low resolution for the whole makefile by default.